# Ubuntu and Windows Boot Manager boot options in BIOS

Tags: boot, grub2

I just put a blank SSD into my laptop, but at boot time there are two options in the boot menu that I don't understand: *Ubuntu* and *Windows Boot Manager*. What are these and how can I remove them? The Ubuntu option is in addition to the drive itself.

[image]

Comment: Those are UEFI entries for OSes previously or still installed.

Comment: Can I remove them?

Comment: Usually disabling *fast boot*  is enough (with fast boot UEFI assumes no changes). If not you can edit it at UEFI settings. Instructions for it varies a lot from one model to another.

Answer (score 0):

So youve probably had windows before Ubuntu and didnt had Ubuntu right away. If you installed Ubuntu (No Dual Boot) you should only have Ubuntu. If you have a Dual Boot you will have Windows Boot Manager.